A group of angels/souls/babies in heaven, the female is being 'reborn' and gets sad that she has to leave her love behind
I have this memory of a film I must have watched some 25 years ago or so (mid-80s), but the film definitely pre-dates this. I would date the film somewhere around the 50s to 60s, it had that really heavily saturated colours kind of look to it. 
Most definitely American.
The thing that sticks in my mind the most is these stereotypical angels (wearing togas, big feathery wings on their backs) and they're happily minding their own business but then the female 'angel' has to be re-born as a baby and the male is all "We'll meet again!" - they might not be angels at all, they may just be 'souls' or something similar.
They were played by young actors (i.e. late teens / early twenties?)
It was a family friendly film, I wouldn't have been watching it at such a young age otherwise! It's such an early memory, that's the only details I can remember of it unfortunately.

Was this a general movie or more of a TV movie?

I'd guess at general movie given its age (not sure when 'tv movie' really became a thing, sorry :( )

Any information on what else happened in the movie? What happened after the sould/angel was reborn?

Sounds like The Blue Bird.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Blue_Bird_(1940_film).  I loved this film.

By reading the plot, I couldn't find any reasons why this is the same movie that OP is looking for =/

This is the scene OP is describing: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Rm5r1oy7Ypk/hqdefault.jpg

@GustavoGabriel It does have a similar scene (the kids are much younger, though), but the answer should definitely explain that.

that's the one! damn, turns out my memory is sketchy.. I guess 25 years will do that to you, but that's definitely the scene that stuck with me. Thank you Steve Smith!

No problem; I was in the same situation myself a few years ago.  I'd seen this film decades previously when I was younger but could only remember the same sad scene where the cherubs are split up, so I was pretty sure this was the one you were looking for.
